# Problem with PageFactory.InitElements in WebDriver API c# .NET

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to create WebDriver UI tests framework using Page Object pattern, using the following URL as a reference: http://www.peternewhook.com/2010/09/automated-testing-pageobjects-webdriver/

As per example I have created 3 classes (see below). The problem is with the line `return PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, page);` in the Search method of the SearchPage class.

When I try to build I get the following error:

> The type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ISearchContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WebDriver

Fair enough, as I am referencing WebDriver.Common.dll, so I tried removing it and added WebDriver.dll to my References and all of a sudden I get the following when I build:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ResultsPage'

and it fails on the same line; when I hover over it, it says:

> Cannot convert expression type 'void' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ResultsPage'.

I also tried referencing both assemblies and thought I could use different usings but it is a no-go, didn't work.

Why can't PageFactory.InitElements be returned when using WebDriver.dll?

Is there a way around it, or can I achieve the same result by changing the architecture slightly?
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

```c#
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Page
    {
        public IWebDriver _driver;

        public Page(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this._driver = driver;
        }
    }
}

using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ResultsPage : Page
    {
        public ResultsPage(IWebDriver driver)
            : base(driver)
        {
        }

        private IWebElement count;

        public string GetPagesReturned()
        {
            return count.Text;
        }
    }
}

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class SearchPage : Page
    {
        public SearchPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
        {
        }

        private IWebElement q;
        private IWebElement go;

        public ResultsPage Search(string searchStatement)
        {
            q.SendKeys(searchStatement);
            go.Click();
            ResultsPage page = new ResultsPage(_driver);
            return PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, page);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `PageFactory.InitElements()` returns void. Rather, it modifies the page you've passed in. Your code should look something like this:

```
public ResultsPage Search(string searchStatement)
{
    q.SendKeys(searchStatement);
    go.Click();
    ResultsPage page = new ResultsPage(_driver);
    PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, page);
    return page;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that. i am still a bit puzzled by the fact that i can return PageFactory.InitElements() if i reference WebDriver.Common assembly. I am not sure if this assembly is now depricated and all the functionality is in WebDriver.dll.

Comment: WebDriver.Common.dll no longer exists in the [current (2.0rc3)](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) release. All core WebDriver code has been migrated to WebDriver.dll. PageFactory is a class in WebDriver.Support.dll, and always has been. `PageFactory.InitElements()` has _always_ returned `void`; I just checked the SVN log of the file to verify that. Also, if this solves your problem, you might want to think about marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Jim, much appreciated. And it does answer my question.

Comment: Anyone know how to use the PageFactory and initlize a List<IWebElement> elements; using the FindsBy annotation.

I can't find any way of doing this yet there are google issues on the selenium google docs site saying this has been fixed in the Java api bindings and in version 2.12 as it was mistaken disabled in 2.11.... I still can't initialize a list. =/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like C# PageFactory does not init private superclass elements (via PageFactory.InitElements) per this:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1189#makechanges

Answer (score 0):

Using PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this); on the constructor of your base page class .

```
public class Page
{
    public IWebDriver _driver;

    public Page(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this._driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JimEvans. But instead of having PAgeFactory code in seperate place, have that in constructor of Results page.

Your results page class should be something like this.
public class result
{
public result(driver,this)
{

}
}